# Error when trying to connect to a local instance

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get a connection from my webapp to a database to get values for a dropdownlist but somehow I always get the same Error at the con.Open. Tells me networkname was not found!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string query = "SELECT HobbyId, Hobby, IsSelected FROM Hobbies";
            //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost/testserver; database=MyDB.dbo; integrated security=true"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            ListItem item = new ListItem();
                            item.Text = sdr["Hobby"].ToString();
                            item.Value = sdr["HobbyId"].ToString();
                            item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsSelected"]);
                            ddlHobbies.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            ddlHobbies.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Hobby--", "0"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the full exception otherwise one can only guess what's wrong. The full exception is what you get with `Exception.ToString()` and includes the call stack.

Comment: Is your database called MyDB.dbo? As a test connect to master.

Comment: Although a message that says the network name wasn't found is **VERY CLEAR**. You used the wrong server name or IP. Or used `/` instead of `\ `

Comment: Since I doubt any of you speaks german it says failed to connect to SQL-Server but it's a local sql-server and it's called testserver so I guess the syntax there is not wrong? And yeah the database is called MyDB.

Comment: @BlackPanic it *is* wrong. You used the wrong slash. And post the *full exception anyway!*. The exception type and call stack says where the error occured and why, even if the question itself is so vague that it omits the exception type and line where the error occured

Comment: PS not my downvote but questions that sound like "the database is broken here is my code" aren't considered good questions. In this case the typo is pretty obvious

Comment: happy that you find it so obvious and yet when I change `/` to `\\` it doesn't fix the problem :) instead I get a different error with networkpath not found..

Comment: @BlackPanic did you tried this as its local instant of DB : SqlConnection("Data Source=testserver;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true;")

Comment: So instead of a single backslash I put a double there and now it works. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a backward slash (`\`) instead of a forward slash (`/`): `server=localhost/testserver` should be `server=localhost\testserver`.

You can also replace `localhost` with a simple dot (`.`): `server=.\testserver`.

Make sure that your SQL server instance is actually running. You can open SQL server configuration manager to check this.

You will also need to enable at least one network protocol for your instance (e.g. named pipes, TCP/IP or shared memory).

Comment: had to use a double backslash but thank you for your answer :)